# Can't use Facebook PHP SDK with Laravel Social Sentry Auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, laravel

I've installed sentry social auth (http://www.getplatform.com/manuals/sentrysocial) on my site http://ratewait.com and it works fine.

I'd like to offer functionality with the Facebook SDK now and having trouble. I installed the SDK with the bundle github.com/kapv89/laravel-fb-sdk-bundle and as a name spaced library like: wrttn.in/b6df85

But every time I call  `$user = $facebook->getUser( );` it returns 0.
I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that I'm using Sentry to authenticate people. Can anyone help?

Thanks
adam

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.

The Sentry Social bundle for laravel stores your access token in a field called Token in a table called social_authentication.

I made a model called social, which links to that table and created a relationship to my User.

Then, added the following code in my controller (this should be moved to a model...)

```
   $user = Sentry::user();
   $user = $user->id;
   $user = User::with('social')->find($user);
   $access_token = $user->social->token;

   $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

   $friends = $facebook->api('/me/');
```

This is probably not the most efficient way, but it works.